# R is unable to detect Rtools

Tags: r, rtools

I recently updated to R version 4.0.5.

I have tools installed in `C:/rtools40`

However, each time I run `install.packages("rJava")`

I get the following:

```
WARNING: Rtools is required to build R packages but is not currently installed. Please download and install the appropriate version of Rtools before proceeding:

https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/Rtools/
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/Pragyaditya Das/Documents/R/win-library/4.0’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/4.0/rJava_1.0-4.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 1127320 bytes (1.1 MB)
downloaded 1.1 MB

package ‘rJava’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked

The downloaded binary packages are in
    C:\Users\Pragyaditya Das\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpuEjxI8\downloaded_package
```

I get a warning that **Rtools is not installed**.

To check if rtools is in path or not, I did `Sys.getenv("PATH")` and I can see that `Rtools` is in path.

In addition to that, I also installed `devtools` and did `find_rtools()`. From this I get `TRUE`.

I don't know what to do and what to look for.

Please help.

TIA.

Comment: And just to verify, but loading `rJava` doesn't work?

Comment: @Laterow Yes, `rJava` doesn't work. Error is: ```> library(rJava)
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘rJava’:
 .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'rJava', details:
  call: inDL(x, as.logical(local), as.logical(now), ...)
  error: unable to load shared object 'C:/Users/Pragyaditya Das/Documents/R/win-library/4.0/rJava/libs/x64/rJava.dll':
  LoadLibrary failure:  The specified module could not be found.```

Comment: Did you try to use R GUI, not RStudio?

Comment: So are you sauing `C:/rtools40/usr/bin` is on the path? Or just a (possibly older) version of R tools. What does `Sys.which("make")` return?

Comment: Try running `pkgbuild::has_rtools(debug=TRUE)` and sharing the output

Comment: @MrFlick I get the following ```make  ""``` on running ```Sys.which("make")```

Comment: @zx8754 I do not have R GUI, however I ran on Rterm and got the same error.

Comment: If `Sys.which("make")` returns "" then you do not have your PATH variable set up correctly. Note when you change your PATH variable, you need to restart R.

Comment: @MrFlick when I run `pkgbuild::has_rtools(debug=TRUE)` I get the following error ```Scanning R CMD config CC...
cc_path:  
'' does not exist
Scanning path...
Scanning registry...
Found C:/rtools40 for 4.0 
[1] TRUE ```

Comment: @MrFlick When I run `Sys.getenv("PATH")`, I get the following ```[1] "C:\\Users\\Pragyaditya Das\\.cargo\\bin;C:\\Users\\Pragyaditya Das\\anaconda3;C:\\Users\\Pragyaditya Das\\anaconda3\\Library\\mingw-w64\\bin;C:\\Users\\Pragyaditya Das\\anaconda3\\Library\\usr\\bin;C:\\Users\\Pragyaditya Das\\anaconda3\\Library\\bin;C:\\Users\\Pragyaditya Das\\anaconda3\\Scripts;C:\\Users\\Pragyaditya Das\\AppData\\Local\\Microsoft\\WindowsApps;C:\\Program Files\\MiKTeX 2.9\\miktex\\bin\\x64\\;C:\\Users\\Pragyaditya Das\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm;C:\\rtools40\\mingw64\\bin;"``` I can see that `rtools40` is there

Comment: @MrFlick I even restarted R. Same error.

Comment: You have `C:\\rtools40\\mingw64\\bin;`, but it should be `C:\\rtools40\\usr\\bin;` according to https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/

Comment: @MrFlick Done. Now my `Sys.getenv()` looks like this `"C:\\Program Files\\R\\R-4.0.5\\bin\\x64;C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Common Files\\Oracle\\Java\\javapath;C:\\Program Files\\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\\CUDA\\v10.1\\bin;C:\\Program Files\\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\\CUDA\\v10.1\\libnvvp;C:\\Rtools\\bin; C:\\Users\\Pragyaditya Das\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm;C:\\rtools40\\mingw64\\bin;;C:\\RTools40;C:\\RTools40\\usr\\bin"` and `Sys.which("make")` returns  `make 
"C:\\RTools40\\usr\\bin\\make.exe" `

Comment: @MrFlick Its working now. Thank you. Please write it as an answer for the benefit of the community.

Comment: @MrFlick Each time I restart R, the PATH resets to `rtools40\migw64\bin`. How to make it permanent

Comment: Well when you installed rtools what exactly did you do? Did you use the control panel to set a system wide PATH environment variable? Did you create an .Rprofile file in your home directly as suggested by the link I shared? Somewhere you entered the wrong value but it’s not clear where.

Comment: @MrFlick I solved the problem. :)

Comment: Well, what was the problem? You can answer your own question below for the benefit of the community.

Comment: @MrFlick a broken rtools installation. I was too tired of all the hassle. So, I uninstalled Rtools and RStudio and now its working perfectly. Sounds a bit too much, but this is what I did.